# Radial time series, appending circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some circles I want to append to a radial time series chart to indicate key events. Equivalent block [here](https://bl.ocks.org/tlfrd/fd6991b2d1947a3cb9e0bd20053899d6).

static picture:

[image]

The code for the circles:

```
 var eventCircles = g.selectAll('.eventCirc')
      .data(eventData)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class','eventCirc')
      .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(0)})
      .attr('r', 5)
      .style('fill', "#003366");
```

The `y(0)` scale seems to work fine, because the units are both in pixels, but I can't figure out how to convert degrees to pixels for use with `cx` -- which is a required attribute for a circle.

The scales are set up as so:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .range([0, fullCircle]);

var y = d3.scaleRadial()
        .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);
```

### Question

How can I use  `d.date` in conjunction with the `x` scale to give me a pixel coordinate for the `cx` attribute (and not simply a degree/radian)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a bit of trigonometry here. Given the specific bl.ocks you linked, this is the math you need:

```
eventCircles.attr('cx', function(d) {
    return y(d.Close) * -Math.sin(x(d.Date) + Math.PI)
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return y(d.Close) * Math.cos(x(d.Date) + Math.PI)
  })
```

In the bl.coks you linked, `Close` is the y value and `Date` is the x value. Change them according to your data.

Here is the forked bl.ocks: https://blockbuilder.org/GerardoFurtado/16adc1bb5677adfa501b3a03b3637d75